# Why am I facing an InvalidArgumentError while training a GLOVE model?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I am trying to train a GLOVE model for sarcasm detection. The error says that during the execution of the the graph computation, there was an invalid index value in the embedding layer.

Am I doing something wrong while initializing the `max_features` and `max_len`?

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sar_df.headline, sar_df.is_sarcastic, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

max_features = 25000
maxlen = 200

print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
print("x_test shape:", x_test.shape)
print("y_train shape:", y_train.shape)
print("y_test shape:", y_test.shape)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=35000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(tokenized_train, maxlen=maxlen)

tokenized_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(tokenized_test, maxlen=maxlen)

print("x_train shape after padding:", x_train.shape)
print("x_test shape after padding:", x_test.shape)

EMBEDDING_FILE = 'glove.6B.100d.txt'

def get_coefs(word, *arr): 
    return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32')

embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.rstrip().rsplit(' ')) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE))

all_embs = np.stack(embeddings_index.values())
emb_mean, emb_std = all_embs.mean(), all_embs.std()
embed_size = all_embs.shape[1]

print("all_embs shape:", all_embs.shape)
print("embed_size:", embed_size)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
nb_words = min(max_features, len(word_index))

embedding_matrix = np.random.normal(emb_mean, emb_std, (nb_words, embed_size))
print("embedding_matrix shape:", embedding_matrix.shape)

for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i >= max_features:
        continue
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

batch_size = 128
epochs = 2
embed_size = 200

# Defining Neural Network
model = Sequential()
# Non-trainable embedding layer
model.add(Embedding(nb_words, output_dim=embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=200, trainable=True))
# LSTM
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, recurrent_dropout=0.5, dropout=0.5)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: use my code and solve it dont forget accep and up vot.nice job